# load different storyboard views in universal app from button xcode

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode7, xcode-storyboard, ios-universal-app

I am building a Universal iOS app.
I have several buttons on the main view which load other view controllers.
I have set up a "Main.storyboard" and an "iPad storyboard.storyboard".
I have made two views in the "main" and the "iPad".
On the "Main" I have set the Storyboard ID's to "FirstCar" and FirstPlayer".
On the "iPad" I have set them to "FirstCarPad" and FirstPlayerPad".
In the General settings I have designated the app as Universal and set the "Main" as the storyboard for the iPhone and the "iPad" for the iPad.

I am using the following code to  launch the view controllers in the storyboards from the initial view.

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
   int height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    if (height == 568.0) {

        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstCar"];

        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];     }

}
else if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ipad storyboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstCarPad"];

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];  }
```

When I tap the first button that accesses the "FirstCar" and "FirstCarPad"
ViewControllers everything works fine but
When I tap the second button that accesses the "FirstPlayer" and "FirstPlayerPad"
viewControllers the app crashes with this

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'FirstPlayerPad''

but I have the viewControllers set up the exact same with the Storyboard ID

I am about to tear my hair out.

Can anybody help me out.

Comment: If you can target iOS 8+, consider using one storyboard and size classes.

Comment: I can access size iOS 8+ but when I use auto layout my app doesn't work correctly.  I am using motion manager and it keeps resetting things so that when I move an object it returns it to the original position.  I wouldn't think this should be that hard though.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work I duplicated the Main.storyboard in the finder renaming it Main-iPad.storyboard then added it to the project.  I then right clicked on the new storyboard and chose Open Source. This showed the storyboard as code and I changed targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"  to targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad".  I then right clicked it again but chose Open Storyboard. 
With the settings set to "Universal" and Main-iPad.storyboard selected as the iPad's storyboard everything works fine. I just have to resize and reposition the elements in each iPad view.  Time consuming but worth it. 
Hope this can be helpful anybody else. I wish when you reconfigured to iPad from iPhone it resized and repositioned the elements in the views but Oh well.